# How to load an online android module at run-time?

Tags: android

Is it possible to split my Android apk of 512MB into different parts or modules.

Compile small part of it into a release Apk (small Apk size) for Play Store.

Then fetch the remaining parts or modules from online or your own server during first time install on a device.

Thats:

1. Small Apk to Google Play Store
2. Fetch remaining big files after first install.

I am using Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, that can be easily achieved if you got to split heavy resources(like images, videos, databases). Here you must write some logic which will download that resources and will work with them after a successful download.

I cant imagine a situation when you must to split a code in a separate module, compiled code is light and dont increase apk size so much as another resources. Code can become heavy when there is a lot of code from libraries, in that case I suggest you to learn about [Proguard Shrink](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html).

Also you can learn why in android is not possible to load java modules in runtime. On of the reasons is performance given by [JIT](https://www.androidcentral.com/android-z-what-jit)

Here a is workaround with ndk [How do I import shared object libraries at runtime in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324956/how-do-i-import-shared-object-libraries-at-runtime-in-android)

Comment: Thank you @Link182 for your suggestion.

After a research I seen such kind of solution in Some Simulator games in the Google Play Store which downloads some extra packages from the internet into the game after first install.

This is a similar solution I want to achieve in with Android Studio.

Any more help or suggestions will appreciated.